# set array key pointer inside a foreach according to a variable php

Tags: php, arrays

So here is an array:

```
$prefectures = Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => グルメ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 住まい
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => 医療・健康・介護
        )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => 美容・ファッション
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => 暮らし
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => ショッピング
    )

    [6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [name] => ペット
    )
)
```

I want to set the key pointer according to a variable inside a foreach loop.

Here is my function:

```
$setKey = '6';

foreach ( $prefectures as $prefecture ) {
            $prefectureId = $prefecture["id"];
            // TODO:
            // set the internal array pointer based on $setKey
}
```

Suppose the current key pointer is at the start, I want to move to the 4th array key.

How could it be done right?

Comment: what do you mean by internal array pointer ? i don't get it

Comment: Perhaps you mean skip, in the loop, data to directly access let's say, ```$prefectures[6]``` ? Maybe ```$prefectures[$setKey]``` ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus could you show me how does it look?

Comment: Not really no, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you need. Could you rephrase your issue without referring to your code ? What do you want to achieve functionally speaking ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus I want to move the current array pointer into say for example, array key 4. The array starts at 0, but I want to skip to 4 directly.

Comment: Using your array, if $setKey = 4 then you want the loop to start processing data on the record with an id of 5 and a name set to "暮らし" ? If so, you could simply use a for loop instead, like this:
```$count = count($prefectures);
for ($i = $setKey; $i < count($prefectures); $i++) { $pref = $prefectures[$i]; // your code; }```